# Cauchy sequence with respect to two different norms

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

The attached picture gives explaination as to how a sequence may be cauchy with respect to one norm but not with respect to another. I have not understood the marked portions. Will be grateful for help[image]!

Comment: There is a typo. Instead of saying that $\|z_n-z_m\|_1 $ does not tend to $0$ as $n,m \to \infty$  it says $\|z_n-z_m\|_1  \to 0$

Comment: The first part you have marked as troublesome is just the definition of difference of two sequences: $(a_n)-(b_n)=(a_n-b_n)$.

Comment: Thank you for the typo comment. However, in the first part, if we assume n is one more than m, we get m zeroes followed by either one ($1/n$) or one $1/(m+1)$. How do we start getting zeros again? Also would be grateful if in the second part, the line above typo mistake is amplified for better understanding

Comment: You are right. It is assumed that $m <n$. The writing of the proof in your link looks very sloppy.

Comment: Thank you very much...